# Deleted whole table when the where clause is not executable statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle11g

I recently had an incident when run a delete statement and it deleted all records. I found the error but could not understand why it could be executed.
I can simply demonstrate the incident like:

```
create table A(
aid int,
description varchar(50)
);

create table B(
bid int,
description varchar(50)
);

insert into A values(1, 'Row 1');
insert into A values(2, 'Row 2');
insert into A values(3, 'Row 3');

insert into B values(22, 'Row 1');
insert into B values(23, 'Row 2');
insert into B values(24, 'Row 3');

delete from A where aid in (select aid from B);
```

The delete statement deleted whole table **A** records, even column **aid** does not exists in table **B**. Why the subquery failed and the statement did not fail? I run it at PostgreSql and Oracle, all is the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Since the table B has no aid column

```
delete from A where aid in (select aid from B);
```

is evaluated as

```
delete from A where aid in (select A.aid from B);
```

But you want

```
delete from A where A.aid in (select B.bid from B);
```

It's good programming practice to qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved.

Comment: Good answer. I cannot commence with the logic, but it is good to know it. Thanks. A small mistake let me pay a big cost.